# Will I have any trouble dual-booting an HP 250 G1

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I was considering buying an HP 250 G1 laptop. I'd like to keep the copy of Windows 8.1 that comes installed on it, but dual boot with Ubuntu.

I've been given the impression that the UEFI might give me trouble and/or that I wont be able to create the appropriate partitions.

Are any of these foreseeable difficulties?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu supports UEFI if I remember correctly. You shouldn't have any problem with it. http://www.instructables.com/id/Dual-Boot-Ubuntu-and-Windows-8-UEFI/

Answer (score 0):

It will work with win7 and Ubuntu. I have one with ssd drive. EXCELENT PERFORMANCE. With uefi and win8 I don't know. The bios is quit messy and you may take time to figure the proper combination of settings.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using Ubuntu 15.04 and W 8.1 on this HP 250 G1 Notebook PC.
I had to reset the bios to disable secure boot, follow the guidelines and set up the partitions in advance.
To boot up press F9 to select boot manager, then this goes to the Grub boot.